# Problem with Tradingview Webhooks - Algo Trading

Tags: networking, webhooks, aiohttp, tradingview-api, amazon-lightsail

We run aiohttp webserver python code on Ubuntu server - Lightsail AWS , this robot receives webhooks of tradingview alerts and base data body trades on Binance Exchange . problem is  we do not receive some alerts from TV and missing it,

note: If 3 seconds pass and take time Trading View automatically cancels the request.

Any ideas?
Thanks

What done :
checked Logs of server , no error found
migrate to AWS Lightsail for better stability
check network connectivity and problems

Comment: That's really vague and without any code to look at, very difficult for anyone to provide any help. However, my first guess would be to look at how messages are being handled and whether something block the event loop or otherwise stop the receiving logic from running for too long.